# Last Modified By is getting updated without user logging in

Tags: trigger, automation

I am recently, seeing an issue in my production org, that cases records are coming from external systems & they were assigning to different users due to assignment rules were configured & process is behaving as expected up to here. Now, what's happening is for some case records, last modified by is getting updated to one specific user.Which shouldn't be. I tried deactivating that user, still last modified by is getting updated to that user

This is happening even after business hours.

Let me know, you thoughts on this!

Appreciate, early response!

Thanks!
Sri

Comment: Do you have any scheduled flows or time based workflow rules? These delayed updates also update the audit fields, do this could be why you're seeing this behavior.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for quick response! Out of curiosity, by using scheduled flows or time based workflow, do we have chance of updating Last Modified By standard field ?

Comment: Yes, any time a record is updated, the Last Modified Date/By is also updated, except for some limited exceptions, like mass-updating picklist values. Delayed/scheduled automations do update the audit fields.

Comment: I agree with you that, if you have scheduled flows or time based workflow submitted with that specific user , then there is a chance of updating records with that User right. 
But the user which is updating here is just a user with basic permissions & OWD is private.